# Error : Java heap space

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, memory

I'm trying to run my project in Eclipse with Tomcat v 6.0.36. The server started but the project doesn't run because of this error:

```
juin 06, 2013 8:12:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Grave: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.my project.base.OBSchedulerInitializerListener
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
```

I've already tried to increase the size in eclipse.ini and also entered to Open luanch configuration -> VM arguments but I still have the same problem.

Here is the class:

```
public class DalContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private static Properties obProperties = null;
    private static ServletContext servletContext = null;

    public static ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return servletContext;
    }

    public static void setServletContext(ServletContext context) {
        DalContextListener.servletContext = context;
    }

    public static Properties getOpenBravoProperties() {
        return obProperties;
    }
}
```

Comment: For those who don't speak French, from Google Translate this says: when sending context initialized event (context initialized) to the instance of listening class (listener) org.my project.base.OBSchedulerInitializerListener java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: What is your OBSchedulerInitializerListener listening method doing?

Comment: You should rewrite your program to use less memory. Try taking a memory profile of it and seeing what object type is taking up most of the memory, and then see where they're being made, and ask if it is necessary to make all of this.

Comment: Has the code ever worked or does this error show every single time?

Comment: I reveive this error every time I try to run my project, I cant rewrite the project its very big and I'm working on it since months ago, I dont know what can I do !!

Comment: public class DalContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
  private static Properties obProperties = null;
  private static ServletContext servletContext = null;

  public static ServletContext getServletContext() {
    return servletContext;
  }

  public static void setServletContext(ServletContext context) {
    DalContextListener.servletContext = context;
  }

  public static Properties getOpenBravoProperties() {
    return obProperties;
  }

Comment: Just a hint: since it's Tomcat that's running out of memory, the fact that you run Eclipse does not really matter here. And `eclipse.ini` will only influence how much memory *Eclipse* gets, it does *not* influence other processes started by Eclipse (such as Tomcat).

Comment: How do you start the Tomcat? If it is from within Eclipse (as a `server`), just edit the `Launch configuration` to add the appropriate `-Xmx` setting.

Comment: maybe check -Xmx option when starting tomcat from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#nonstandard

Comment: I edited lunch configuration and added -Xms256m -Xmx512m it is correct ? I tried to run the project but no result the same error appeared !

Comment: So, thank you guys for trying to help me even if we dont find the solution !! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to solve heap space error in java is to increase the maximum heap size by using JVM options. Try the following configuration in VM options.

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m
```

Comment: what do you mean by using JVM options ?

Comment: you mean that I have to add -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m  in VM arguments in Lunch Configuration ?

Comment: @user2458801 Try this http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: @user2458801 Restart your tomcat server and try again.

Comment: I did it !! nothing !! the same error, what can I do ? Is there any other sollutions ?

Comment: @user2458801 have you add the same parameters in your server run configuration ?? in run configurations you will be having an option like VM arguments add these properties in there. And restart your server and  try again.

Comment: I did it and restarted the server but I still have the same problem !

Comment: I want to know if the cause of the problem is related with the memory of my computer ?